# Get dimensions of UIView Class for CGRects?

Tags: ios, uiview, core-graphics, bounds, cgrect

I am currently working on an app that draws a series of rectangles (`CGRect`) on a view and sizes them based on the size of the UIView. This code is contain in a class file that inherits UIView (rectangle.h/rectangle.m). I cannot for some reason use `self.view.bounds.height` or `self.view.bounds.width` to get the values I need. I am using the overridden method "`drawrect`" that is built into the class. How can I get the view size? or if thats not possible, how can I implement this?

Comment: umm.. `self.bounds.width` and `self.bounds.height`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
self.view.bounds.size.width 
self.view.bounds.size.height
```

or

if self class is itself a `UIView`

```
self.bounds.size.width 
self.bounds.size.height
```

Comment: Cant accepts this as an answer for another 5 minutes, but looks like I've got a lot to learn haha... thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can get the view size using the following :

```
CGSize viewSize = self.view.frame.size;

NSLog(@"View Size : %@",NSStringFromCGSize(self.view.frame.size));
```